# Module not found on run

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below file structure:

```
project/
  Scripts/
    dummy.py
    Tests/
      Test.py
```

I have a .py file in Scripts called 'dummy' with the below content:

```py
def basic(a,b):
  return a + b
```

And then in the Tests folder, I have 'Test.py' with the below:

```py
from dummy import basic
```

When entering this line, I'm getting the prompts, so it recognizes both the file, and the function, but on running the script, it fails at the import, saying module not found. What is the problem here?

Comment: How is Python supposed to know how to find that file?  It doesn't go trolling through your directory tree.  You need to make sure that `Scripts` is in the Python path, no matter what the "current directory" is when you run.  You can do that using something like `sys.path.append( os.dirname(__file__) + '/..' )`.

Comment: Generally, `import` will only look in the current folder.  If the module is located in some other folder, as is the case here, you have to tell it specifically where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Add the Scripts folder to the sys.path variable

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "../Scripts")
from dummy import basic
```

**OR**

Use the PYTHONPATH environment variable

```py
SET PYTHONPATH="..\Scripts"
```

**OR**

Add the script to the the current directory

Comment: While this is correct, I'd suggest changing the order: 1) set PYTHONPATH (either using SET on Windows / export on Linux/Mac or just setting it directly before the command on Linux/Mac), 2) injecting it in the code and 3) changing script location. This is, because setting PYTHONPATH is the "correct" thing to do and inserting modules in your code is very fragile and unexpected from a software engineering point of view. Module imports should not have such unexpected side effects because that makes it harder to reuse them in the future, and breaks very quickly, e.g., if the relative path changes.